# 'Invalid bean definition' when migrating Spring Boot 2.0.6 to 2.1.0 with EvaluationContextExtensionSupport and custom PermissionEvaluator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In Spring Boot 2.1.0 `EvaluationContextExtensionSupport` is deprecated and https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/query/spi/EvaluationContextExtensionSupport.html says to *Implement EvaluationContextExtension directly*

Even though it is only deprecated, it instantly starting failing on this upgrade with this stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration; factoryMethodName=methodSecurityInterceptor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]] for bean 'methodSecurityInterceptor': There is already [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=methodSecurityConfiguration; factoryMethodName=methodSecurityInterceptor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [ournamespace/configuration/MethodSecurityConfiguration.class]] bound.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:894)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:274)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
...and so on
```

I don't explicitly override this bean, so I'm guessing this is just a side effect of what we're doing in our current code. If I do allow bean overriding with `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` as per https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#bean-overriding then I simply get another exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider$EvaluationContextExtensionAdapter@10dfbbbb at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$throwingMerger$0(Collectors.java:133) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
```

However, I don't even want to override any bean behavior, the goal is to get a custom permission evaluator working again the way Spring intends it to work.

**This is how it did work in the last version:**

In Spring Boot 2.0.6 we had the following to get our custom PermissionEvaluator class to work:

A class that extended `EvaluationContextExtensionSupport`

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.spi.EvaluationContextExtensionSupport;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

public class SecurityEvaluationContextExtension extends EvaluationContextExtensionSupport {

    @Override
    public String getExtensionId() {
        return "security";
    }

    @Override
    public SecurityExpressionRoot getRootObject() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            return new SecurityExpressionRoot(authentication) {
        };
    }
}
```

And then a class where the expression handler is created with our permission evaluator, and with a @Bean with a `EvaluationContextExtension`

```
import ournamespace.security.CustomPermissionEvaluator;
import ournamespace.security.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.spi.EvaluationContextExtension;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    private final CustomPermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler =
                new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);
        return expressionHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    EvaluationContextExtension securityExtension() {
        return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
    }
}
```

And finally we have this in an otherwise mostly empty class:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   ...
}
```

This is because the custom permission evaluator never did apply to all methods if we just put this in the `MethodSecurityConfiguration` class.
The server in question is an oauth2 resource server so we don't configure anything else in the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. We also implement our own `UserDetails` and we extend the `DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter`, if this is in any way relevant for the new solution.

I have tried implementing `EvaluationContextExtension` class directly, as stated in the deprecation warning. It's just a simple modification by changing the extends interface to `implements EvaluationContextExtension`.
I have also tried changing to the seemingly newer package `org.springframework.data.spel.spi`

I've tried deleting our own `SecurityEvaluationContextExtension` and returning https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/data/repository/query/SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.html as a bean directly but for some reason that data package isn't available in Spring Boot 2.1.0

I've tried just removing the definition of that bean altogether.

All these things result in various 'invalid bean definition' errors on startup.

Does anyone know where to find a migration guide or any other resource on how this is supposed to work now?

Just for reference sake, the actual `CustomPermissionEvaluator` class:

```
import ournamespace.configuration.Constants;
import ournamespace.exception.InternalException;
import ournamespace.model.Account;
import ournamespace.model.Member;
import ournamespace.model.Project;
import ournamespace.repository.MemberRepository;
import ournamespace.service.ServiceUtil;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.access.PermissionEvaluator;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.Serializable;

import static ournamespace.model.MemberStatus.JOINED;
import static ournamespace.model.ProjectRole.*;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    private final MemberRepository memberRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication auth, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
        if (targetDomainObject == null)
            return false;

        if (!(permission instanceof String))
            return false;

        if (auth == null)
            return false;

        Account account = ServiceUtil.getAccount(auth);

        if (targetDomainObject instanceof Project)
            return hasPermissionOnProject(account, (Project) targetDomainObject, (String) permission);
        //and so on
    }
}
```

And an example on how it's used:

```
public interface ProjectRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Project, UUID> {

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#project, " + Constants.WRITE + ")")
    <S extends Project> S save(@Param("project") S project);
}
```

Comment: Can you also add error stack trace?

Comment: @SukhpalSingh I added a piece of stacktrace that the deprecated code now throws. Stacktraces for all the things I tried would go a bit too far, it's a lengthy post as it is and I have no idea if they made sense.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek Going back to your comment about deleting your `SecurityEvaluationContextExtension`. This bean gets exposed automatically by Spring Boot when the spring-security-data and spring-boot-starter-security dependencies are present. Can you delete your custom class and delete the bean method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I took your code and created a sample app from it. I posted it here:

https://github.com/jzheaux/stackoverflow-53410526

Your `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation is on `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. You also have a class that extends `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`. This can cause some ordering issues at startup at times, which may be what you are seeing => two `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler`s get created as well as two `EvaluationContextExtension`s.

Whether this is precisely the case or not (I'm guessing that it is), when I matched your `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` with your custom `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`, things started up fine.

Also, though, it seems that your custom `EvaluationContextExtension` is very similar to the Spring Security default. You might consider removing that class as well as the corresponding bean method, if you can, since Spring Boot exposes one automatically when you have `spring-boot-starter-security` and `spring-security-data` as dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I will have a look and try some suggestions.
We had to put our @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity on that WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter because otherwise for random repositories it would not trigger the custom PermissionEvaluator. This was when we were still using Spring Data Rest though. You can see my self-answered question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48868723/144578 if interested.

Comment: Ignore what I said on the custom PermissionEvaluator not triggering on random repositories. It's not triggered if I move the @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity annotation, full stop. I just didn't notice on other repo's because there it wasn't needed to apply security correctly, as there it was already done at the time of retrieving the entity from the database.

Comment: How would you suggest I should be registering a custom PermissionEvaluator the idiomatic way, in such a way that it is triggered for every method call regardless of how it enters the application?

Comment: Just to be clear, I can confirm that the `CustomPermissionEvaluator` in the posted project does indeed get invoked when invoking `ProjectRepository#save`. If all you need to do is customize the permission evaluator, though, you can expose it as a bean, and Spring Security will pick it up, i.e. delete MethodSecurityConfiguration.java. You will still need to have `PreAuthorize` either way, though. It won't be triggered for "every method" in the application.

Comment: If you can alter the posted project in such a way as to reproduce the behavior you are seeing, it may help me to see where I'm misunderstanding things.

Comment: Interesting, I've tried merely exposing a bean of CustomPermissionEvaluator but then I'm running into another issue that in fact a DenyAllPermissionEvaluator seems to get triggered on every method instead. I googled a bit and it looks related to this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5272 but that should be a closed issue. This is with spring-security-data 5.1.1 in the pom and Spring Boot 2.1.0 btw.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort but I don't see any way to reproduce this in a small contained case right now. I will try to strip down my project bit by bit later to get a minimum reproduction to file an issue, but for now I decided to apply the fairly straightforward security I had in my service classes and stop the use of the PermissionEvaluator, I don't think I'm experienced enough with Spring yet to understand its magic. I will accept your answer as it did explain me more about Spring and helped me see the problem with putting @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity elsewhere though.

Comment: Some last comments, I didn't say this explicitly but I did look at your project and I can't see an obvious difference between my and your setup, you seem to have matched it quite well but it's still not behaving the same way. Oh and when I said every method I did mean the ones with hasPermission on it, maybe that wasn't clear.

Comment: Okay, @SebastiaanvandenBroek, don't hesitate to ping me on Gitter next time you get time to try again. I try to hang out there every now and again.

Answer (score 2):

You're overriding `methodSecurityInterceptor` bean. It was working previously as bean overriding was allowed.

> Bean overriding has been disabled by default to prevent a bean being accidentally overridden. If you are relying on overriding, you will need to set spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding to true.

[Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#bean-overriding](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#bean-overriding)

Comment: I am not directly overriding this bean, it’s a result of the combination of things we’re doing. I would prefer not to turn a switch and have a workaround that may or may not work for a while, but to truly get rid of @Deprecated code and find a way to make this work the way it is supposed to in this new version of Spring Boot.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek I think current error you're facing isn't related to any other upgrade(s) in boot. Maybe downgrading then checking logs will help you to check whether you were overriding bean earlier too. But did it work after setting this property?

Comment: It is related to this, absolutely. I only changed the version from 2.0.1 to 2.1.0.
Honestly I don't even want to try overriding something that isn't standard, because these classes are also deprecated and bound to disappear. I am sure there is a way in Spring to still have this kind of more fine-grained method security and I want to use that in the idiomatic way.

Comment: Alright, just to give it a shot I did try setting that property. That just means the exception changes to 
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider$EvaluationContextExtensionAdapter@10dfbbbb
 at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$throwingMerger$0(Collectors.java:133) ~[na:1.8.0_162]`

Comment: Is `EvaluationContextExtension` bean still present or no? It would be helpful to provide sample project and a test case

Comment: All that is present is in the code provided in the question. Yes I will consider just filing an issue with Spring but to minimize the application (which also depends on an oauth2 server) to that level will take some time.